# Check Facebook access token rights for an app

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

User authorized FB app number 12345678 to access his info

User access token is 11223344556677889900

User goes to Facebook dashboard and deauthorized the FB app number 12345678

How I can chceck if the user can stil use the access token 11223344556677889900 to call some FB.ui methods on the app number 12345678 ?

Answer (score 1):

If you use the javascript SDK, you should call

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response){
//handle response here
})
```

This will tell you if the user is connected to your app or not. If they are, you'll get a fresh, valid, access token returned.

Docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/

Answer (score 0):

No, check this paragraph in Facebook docs :

> **App Deauthorization**
>
> When a user of your app removes it in the App Dashboard or blocks the app in the News Feed, your app can be notified by specifying a Deauthorize Callback URL in the Developer App. During app removal we will send an HTTP POST request containing a single parameter, signed_request, which contains the user id (UID) of the user that just removed your app. **You will not receive an user access token in this request and all existing user access tokens will be automatically expired**.

[Link to said doc](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/)

Comment: I know this, but I'm working on an app where the callback was not used, and the access tokens of the users are stored in the db. Lots ogf them invalid right now, and I want to check which of them

Comment: ok, i get it now, but my answer is still valid, because if the user comes again to your app, she/he will be asked to authorize your app again, and using the old access token will not work for sure. Facebook keeps that info, and a new access token will be generated, which you can rewrite to your db. **The old access token will not work for any FB.ui or any other graph api method that requires an access token**. However if you want to know which tokens are invalid in your db, then , that will be difficult to work out, i mean i can't think of a way now. If you are doing authentication before ....

Comment: .... calling any Fb.ui method then there is nothing to be worried about. Regardless of how you are doing the authentication, i.e server side or client side(Javascript).